# Property 'checked' does not exist on type 'TElement'

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angular, typescript

- I am new to typescript.
- I have a working prototype in fiddle where if I use this it doesnt throw any error.
  http://jsfiddle.net/61ufvtpj/2/
- but  in typescript I use this line if(this.checked){ it throws this error [ts] Property 'checked' does not exist on type 'TElement'.
- can you tell me how to fix it so that in future I will fix it by myself.
- providing relevant code below and whole code in the gist.

https://gist.github.com/niniyzni/4faea080e53eb0c7155ddd8fb635a46c

```or-tag-here
 $(document).on('change', '#playerFlagCheck', function () {

            if(this.checked){ //[ts] Property 'checked' does not exist on type 'TElement'.
                $('#editIconplayer').addClass("gridUpdateIcon");
                alert("I am inside if");
            }else{
                alert("I am inside else");
                if(!$('#editIconplayer').hasClass("gridUpdateIcon")){
                    $('#editIconplayer').removeClass("gridUpdateIcon");
                }
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your event handler it is creating a new context, [to more about check me](https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-scope-in-javascript). So, `this` is not longer referring to the controller itself.

This must solve the problem:

```
const vm = this;
$(document).on('change', '#playerFlagCheck', function () {
   if(vm.checked) {
     $('#editIconplayer').addClass("gridUpdateIcon");
       alert("I am inside if");
     } else {
       alert("I am inside else");
       if(!$('#editIconplayer').hasClass("gridUpdateIcon")) {
         $('#editIconplayer').removeClass("gridUpdateIcon");
       }
     }

});
```

Comment: hey thanks for your reply...I updated the code but right now I am getting an error like this property checked does not exist on type playerBulkUpdate....is there any other problem?

Comment: playerBulkUpdate is the name of your controller ? Show us more code (and the `html`) to help you.

Comment: hey export class playerBulkUpdate { is the class name https://gist.github.com/niniyzni/4faea080e53eb0c7155ddd8fb635a46c#file-icon-this-ts-L22

Comment: hey paapu below code is working  only for one row....but it should work for multiple rows...and if I unselect that time also image should stay...any idea how to fix it

Comment: hey here is the html https://gist.github.com/niniyzni/4faea080e53eb0c7155ddd8fb635a46c#file-icon-this-ts-L1834

Answer (score 0):

Try it. you should also use prop or attr

```
 $(document).on('change', '#playerFlagCheck', function () {
       if($(this).is(':checked')) {
         $('#editIconplayer').addClass("gridUpdateIcon");
           alert("I am inside if");
         } else {
           alert("I am inside else");
           if(!$('#editIconplayer').hasClass("gridUpdateIcon")) {
             $('#editIconplayer').removeClass("gridUpdateIcon");
           }
         }

});
```

Comment: hey its working only for one row....but it should work for multiple rows...and if I unselect that time also image should stay...any idea how to fix it